# Inserting to std:: map while existing elements are running threads

Tags: c++, memory-management, thread-safety, resize, stdmap

Given an std::map which holds pairs of std::string,A, where A is an object the spawns and manages it's own thread.
Is there a danger to inserting to the map while other elements exist in it? Ie. they are managing their own threads.
My concern is that inserting more elements can cause the existing A objects to be moved in memory, causing risk to the internal threads. Is that the case?

What about std:: unordered_map?

(The question is not about concurrent read/write access to the map itself)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pedantically, this entirely depends on what "spawns and manages it's own thread" means. It is not possible to have a 100% accurate answer to this without actually knowing what that is all about. For example, if an object's method starts a detached `std::thread`, and the new execution thread does not refer to the object that started it, then ...nobody cares. The execution thread does not refer to the object that started it, and its fate can be up to the winds.

But, practically, you're obviously implying that the execution thread does reference its starting object, in some form or fashion, and the question is whether the object becomes invalidated.

There is a very simple way you can answer your own question: simply look up the technical reference for whatever container you're interested in, and look up when, and how, the container moves any objects in the container. There's your answer.

If you were to look this up for your `std::map`, you will discover that inserting new values into the map does not invalidate any iterators to other values in the map, and does not move it. Your object is safe.

Comment: AFAIK, insertion into `unordered_map` may invalidate iterators, but not pointers or references. Therefore, elements cannot be "moved in memory" (which was OP's concern).

Comment: You 're maybe right, hence I'll hedge my bets...